# TFS no pending changes, moved source code

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, version-control, azure-devops

I have had hardware issues and temporary worked on a vm in the cloud. I had all source code checking in [Team Foundation Service](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/) online. Everything was fine on the vm. When I got my pc back I just took everything out tfs and still no problem.
Until I found out that for one of my projects I did not check in the file and commited it.
Luckily I had a backup on an external hdd. So I manually merged my source code and some files and started Visual Studio again and wanted to commit my manually merge effort.
It started with a prompt about

> tf workspaces /updateComputerName:old-pc-name /collection:url-to-tfs

Which I ran from the developer command prompt for vs2015 (community edition)
But the next restart VS said it would treat the project as without source control because of some workspace issue.

I have like no clue on how to work with tfs. I just check in and commit stuff and am always struggling with workplaces, collections. 
Managing the workplaces seems okay to me. Nothing strange there. I did remove the workplace for the temp (cloud) vm.

[image]

in the source control explorer in vs 2015 it has the right local path there too. But my solution explorer does not give me the option to check in anymore. just add to source control. while the project is mapped.

I don't understand how copying files over from my backup hdd to my source code which is under source control messed up my source control so badly.

**edit** I have installed tfs power tools and that gave me the message that it is not possible to run it on local workspaces.

> tfpt online /adds /deletes /diff /noprompt /recursive directory-name

My VS says that it could not find the source control etc. and that it will use the solution as if it has no source control. When I have connected to the team and selected the map button in **source control explorer** I got the error that it is already mapped. But VS shows it is unmapped now?

[image]

**edit2** I have started over. mapped the folders local and remote and got all the source code from the online tfs and started to manually merge again with a 3rd party merge/diff tool. 
When I open a file in VS and merge/diff and make changes and save the file. The file auto reloads in visual studio displaying the changes. But according to visual studio there is no need to check it into source control. So it does display the file change, but not the required check-in...

Answer (score 0):

The workspace is basically just a mapping between local and server paths. If you copy the changes over from your backup you still have to check-out the files in order for them to show up in your Pending changes.

You can use the command line tool *tfpt* that is part of [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) to look through your files and figure out which has changed:

```
tfpt online /adds /deletes /diff /noprompt /recursive directory-name
```

After you run the command you will have the changed or added files in your pending changes and can thereafter compare and commit them to the repository.

Alternatively you could start over:

1. Get the current server source to a new local workspace
2. Make a recursive checkout on the folder
3. Copy the backup files over
4. [optional] to limit the number of pending changes run *tfpt uu /recursive* to undo the unchanged
5. Compare the changes
6. Check-in

Comment: Will try. Thanks. I hope this works because visual studio gives me the option to add solution to source control now. So no other source control options. Really strange.

Comment: `This command doesn't support local workspaces.` is the message I receive. I have totally messed up the TFS binding stuff I think... vs says solution source control could not be found etc. threaded as no source control. etc.

Comment: I guess that you still have the changes from your backup. So I would suggest to start over. 1. Get the current server source to a new local workspace, 2. make a recursive checkout on the folder, 3. copy the backup files over, 4. [optional] to limit the number of pending changes run *tfpt uu /recursive* to undo the unchanged, 5. compare the changes, 6. check-in

Comment: I have started over. And I am copying changes to the specific files. Wanted to do a test check-in to see if it was working. Visual Studio says that there is no change. but it does display the changes I made using a 3rd party merge/diff tool...